# When i click on a select the scrollbar space disappear and all the page content move right

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui, react-hooks

I already use `overflow-y: scroll;` to always reserve the scrollbar space and solve content moving when the scrollbar appears. But when I click on a select element, this scrollbar space disappears. How can I maintain this scrollbar space even when I click on a select?

I am using material-ui components and sass to customize it.

Comment: I can't help you without examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem reserving the space of the scrollbar on width.

Instead of using `width:100%`, change to 100vw and decrease the size of the scrollbar(in this case is 16px)

```
body {
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to your problem [here](https://codepen.io/stevenlewis/pen/hubpL). You can use the following JavaScript to make the scrollbar always appear:

```
.frame::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 11px;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```